# monacaクラウドIDEのプレビュー機能でconsole.logを出力させたい

Tags: javascript, monaca

monacaクラウドIDEでAndroid/iOSアプリを作成しています。
作成したコードをデバッグする際に、現状はAndroid端末かiOS端末のデバッガーを使用しています。
monacaクラウドIDEのプレビュー機能でデバッグを行いたいのですが、console.logの結果をブラウザに出力できません。
monacaクラウドIDEのプレビュー機能でconsole.logの出力結果を表示させる方法はありますか。

手元のスマートフォン上のデバッガーを起動することなく、PC上のmonacaクラウドIDEのみで、デバッグを行いたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: monaca クラウドの仕様なので、monaca クラウドに問い合わせた方が良いと思います。

Comment: @mattn
コメントありがとうございます。
下記のmonacaの公式HPにてスタックオーバフローにて質問するよう誘導されたため、質問しました。  
[Monaca](https://monaca.mobi/ja/support/index)  
  
以下引用  
_Monacaフォーラムでは、Q＆A基盤であるStack Overflow上にてMonacaでのアプリ開発中に発生した技術的な課題について他のユーザーへアドバイスを求めたり、開発に際して役に立つ情報を他のユーザーと共有できます。_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ブラウザによって異なるかもしれませんが次の自分はChromeで次のやり方で `console.log` を確認しています。

1. プレビューウィンドウを選択した状態で「F12」を押す。
2. ブ ラウザのDevToolsが開くので「Console」にてログを確認。